# Paging among multiple aggregate root

Tags: domain-driven-design, paging, aggregateroot

I'm new to DDD so please executes me if some term/understanding are bit off. But please correct me and any advice are appreciated.

Let's say I'm doing a social job board site, and I've identified my aggregate roots: Candidates, Jobs, and Companies. Very different things/contexts so each has own database table, repository, and service. But now I have to build a Pinterest style homepage where data blocks show data for either a Candidate, a Job, or a Company.

Now the tricky part is the data blocks have to be ordered by the last time something happened to the aggregate it represents (a company is liked/commented, or a job was update, etc), and paging occurs in form of infinite scrolling, again just like Pinterest. Since things occur to these aggregates independently I do not have a way to know how many of what aggregate is on any particular page. (but if I did btw, say a table that tracks aggregates' last update time, have I no choice but to promote this to be another aggregate root, with it's own repository?)

Where would I implement the paging logic? I read somewhere that there should be one service per repository per aggregate root, so should I sort and page in controller (I'm using MVC by the way)? Or should there be a independent Application Service that does cross boundary stuff like this? Either case I have to fetch ALL entities for ALL aggregates from db?

That's too many questions already but I'm basically asking:

1. Is paging presentation, business, or persistence logic? Which horizontal layer?
2. Where should cross boundary code reside in DDD? Which vertical stack?

Answer (score 0):

Several things come to mind.

- How fresh does this aggregated data need to be? I doubt realtime is going to add much value. Talk to a business person and bargain for some latency. This will allow you to build a simpler solution to the problem.
- Why not have some process do the scanning, aggregation, sorting and store the result of that asynchronously? Doesn't even need to be in a database (Redis). The bargained latency could be the interval at which to run your process.
- Paging is hardly a business decision concern in your example. You just need to provide infinite scrolling and some ajax calls that fetch the cached, aggregated, sorted information. This has little to do with DDD.
- Your UI artifacts and the aggregation, sorting process seem to be very much a thing on their own, working together with the data or - better yet - a datacomponent of each context that provides the data in the desired format.